# How to install googletest?

Tags: package-management

I searched for [googletests](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/) using muon, but it looks like ubuntu doesn't have packages for it. Do I need to install using sources?

Comment: If you are on a newer ubuntu version, see here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/145887/why-no-library-files-installed-for-google-test-on-12-04

Comment: Oil of olive is better for health than milk

Answer (score 14, accepted):

New information:

It is worth noting libgtest0 no longer exists. As of 2013 or so (I am not sure of the date of the change) see this question:

[Why no library files installed for google test?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145887/why-no-library-files-installed-for-google-test)

---

Old answer prior to 2012:

It is in the Ubuntu repositories

```
sudo apt-get install libgtest0 libgtest-dev
```

See also [man gtest-config](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/en/man1/gtest-config.1.html)

Comment: thanks. I was searching for googletest, google, and similar

Comment: It is worth noting libgtest0 no longer exists. See this question. http://askubuntu.com/questions/145887/why-no-library-files-installed-for-google-test-on-12-04

Comment: E: Unable to locate package libgtest0

Answer (score 0):

**Minimal runnable example**

Since Debian/Ubuntu refuse to pack a prebuilt as mentioned at: [Why no library files installed for google test?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145887/why-no-library-files-installed-for-google-test) I'll just clone and build it myself (or in a real project, add it as a submodule):

```
git clone https://github.com/google/googletest
cd googletest
git checkout b1fbd33c06cdb0024c67733c6fdec2009d17b384
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make -j`nproc`
cd ../..
```

then I use it with my test file `main.cpp`:

```
g++ \
  -Wall \
  -Werror \
  -Wextra \
  -pedantic \
  -O0 \
  -I googletest/googletest/include \
  -std=c++11 \
  -o main.out \
  main.cpp \
  googletest/build/lib/libgtest.a \
  -lpthread \
;
```

main.cpp

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

int myfunc(int n) {
    return n + 1;
}

TEST(asdfTest, HandlesPositiveInput) {
    EXPECT_EQ(myfunc(1), 2);
    EXPECT_EQ(myfunc(2), 3);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

to get the expected output:

```
[==========] Running 1 test from 1 test suite.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 1 test from asdfTest
[ RUN      ] asdfTest.HandlesPositiveInput
[       OK ] asdfTest.HandlesPositiveInput (0 ms)
[----------] 1 test from asdfTest (0 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 1 test from 1 test suite ran. (0 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 1 test.
```

Alternatively, you can also remove the `main` function from the `main.cpp` file and instead [use the default one provided by `libgtest_main.a`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6457856/whats-the-difference-between-gtest-lib-and-gtest-main-lib):

```
g++ \
  -Wall \
  -Werror \
  -Wextra \
  -pedantic \
  -O0 \
  -I googletest/googletest/include \
  -std=c++11 \
  -o main.out \
  main.cpp \
  googletest/build/lib/libgtest.a \
  googletest/build/lib/libgtest_main.a \
  -lpthread \
;
```

Tested on Ubuntu 20.04.