# Why no library files installed for google test?

Tags: application-development, shared-library

The libgtest-dev package seems only install header files to the system, but not the static and dynamic libraries which should be installed under /usr/lib.

Is it a bug?

Comment: Since it's intentional, it's not a bug; yet the situation is utterly confusing. I therefore filed a bug report at https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=802587.

Comment: ugh... does boost's testing framework "just work" ?

Comment: Some reasons from google: https://github.com/google/googletest/issues/2184.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

> Is it a bug?

No, it's deliberate:

```
gtest (1.6.0-1ubuntu2) precise; urgency=low

  * Stop distributing static library (although still build it, to ensure gtest
    works).  Upstream recommends against shipping the libary at all, just the
    source. (See: http://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/FAQ)
    The Debian maintainer plans to do this also (see BTS: 639795); do it in
    Ubuntu now to fulfil MIR requirements.
```

#### To build static libraries

```
cd /usr/src/gtest
sudo cmake .
sudo make
sudo mv libg* /usr/lib/
```

---

Edit:

The names have changed slightly over the years, though the process remains the same.  In Ubuntu 17.04:

```
sudo apt-get install libgtest-dev
cd /usr/src/googletest/googletest
sudo mkdir build
cd build
sudo cmake ..
sudo make
sudo cp libgtest* /usr/lib/
cd ..
sudo rm -rf build
```

Comment: Thanks! I've built the libraries in this way. Just thought that it might not be an *official* approach for a .deb package.

Comment: The Google works in mysterious ways! :) Glad it helped.

Comment: I'd rather create a temporary directory for building, and not pollute `/usr/src/` with binaries.

Comment: Copy-paste version: `cd /usr/src/gtest && sudo cmake . && sudo make && sudo mv libg* /usr/lib/ && cd -`

Comment: Actually reason described [here](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/FAQ#Why_is_it_not_recommended_to_install_a_pre-compiled_copy_of_Goog) can be applied to **any** library. For example if boost is linked with libstdc++ and you want to use libc++ you need to recompile boost from sources. So it's strange, IMHO

Comment: I can confirm it still works even on Ubuntu 14.04. A post-install warning would be nice, though.

Comment: This is freaking asinine. Why the hell wouldn't they ship the library for the source? Or at least have the package install build it automatically.

Comment: General idea is still the same, but the directory names seem to have changed.  In 17.04, I found it in /usr/src/googletest/googletest/.

Comment: Is there a requirement to make symbolic links with the new folder name "googletest" or the old folder name "gtest"?  `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libgtest.a /usr/local/lib/googletest/libgtest.a`
`sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libgtest_main.a /usr/local/lib/googletest/libgtest_main.a`

Comment: do you have an update for Ubuntu 20.04 ?

Answer (score 23):

Improving on izx's answer I would have used cmake this way:

```
sudo cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE .
```

and I would attempt an out-of-source build:

```
cd /tmp
mkdir .build
cd .build
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE /usr/src/gtest/
make
sudo mv libg* /usr/lib/
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that the [recommended](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/README.md#incorporating-into-an-existing-cmake-project) way by google is to have your existing project pull the gtest source code in.

Alternatively, when using with CMake, you can use `add_subdirectory` to add the gtest source that came with `libgtest-dev` since it by default goes into `/usr/src/googletest`.

The following will work

```
add_subdirectory(/usr/src/googletest gtest)
target_link_libraries(your_executable gtest)
```

Comment: recommended doesn't mean they do it themselves. See: https://github.com/google/shaderc