# not gtest folder in /usr/src/ folder

Tags: software-installation, application-development, shared-library

I am trying to install gtest in 18.04. I ran

```bsh
sudo apt-get install libgtest-dev
```

but when I go in to the folder  `/usr/src/` there is not gtest or googletest folder.

According to this:

- https://gist.github.com/Cartexius/4c437c084d6e388288201aadf9c8cdd5
- [Why no library files installed for google test?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145887/why-no-library-files-installed-for-google-test)

There should be a directory for me to build gtest.

Does anyone know what is going on?

Comment: I meant to write /urs/src I updated the questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to try reinstalling [both](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/googletest/filelist) [packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/libgtest-dev/filelist) by:

```
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall googletest libgtest-dev
```

and retry directory listing.

Comment: thanks that worked perfectly!!! Can you please explain why this worked?

Comment: I'm not really sure, but glad it works :)