# FIX8 protocol compile issue

Tags: package-management, compiling, c++, make

I am trying to compile the fix8 framework. According to the documentation the only dependency is the `poco library` which I have successfully compiled/installed. When I run `make` on the `fix8` folder I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgtest

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgtest_main

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

make[2]: *** [libutest.la] Error 1

make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/kostas/Desktop/test/fix8-1.4.0/utests'

make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1

make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/kostas/Desktop/test/fix8-1.4.0'

make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Does the`gtest` package depend on the package `libgtest-dev` ? I have read that the package `libgtest-dev` is no longer available?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The option is `-l`, and the library you're looking for is `gtest`. Where did you read about unavailability? A reliable site? Also, without knowing which version of Ubuntu you're running, one cannot reliably discuss software (un)availibility. On my Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS, there are several choices:

```
$ apt-cache search gtest
autopkgtest - automatic as-installed testing for Debian packages
lxc-tests - Linux Containers userspace tools (test binaries)
debian-policy - Debian Policy Manual and related documents
gnome-desktop-testing - runner for GNOME installed tests
gtester2xunit - Helper for converting gtester xml output to xunit.
libdist-zilla-plugin-podspellingtests-perl - Backward-compatibility wrapper around Dist::Zilla::Plugin::Test::PodSpelling
libdist-zilla-plugin-test-podspelling-perl - Author tests for POD spelling
libgtest-dev - Google's framework for writing C++ tests - header files
libxorg-gtest-data - X.Org dummy testing environment for Google Test - data
libxorg-gtest-dev - X.Org dummy testing environment for Google Test - headers
libxorg-gtest-doc - X.org dummy testing environment for Google Test - documentation
pkg-perl-autopkgtest - collection of autopktest scripts for Perl packages
python-nose-timer - timer plugin for nosetests - Python 2.x
python3-nose-timer - timer plugin for nosetests - Python 3.x
```

And yes, it looks like you've found an undocumented dependency.

Comment: My ubuntu version is `14.04 LTS`. I have tried to `sudo apt-get install libgtest-dev` but its already installed ? What am I missing? Also thanks for pointing out that `-l` is the option. I will edit my post!

Comment: also about `gtest` http://askubuntu.com/questions/97626/how-to-install-googletest